# OpenCV ROI background padding

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to focus on a Region of Interest on the face by using Numpy cropping. For large images, I have no trouble. But for smaller ones, I can find the face and find the matching bounding box, but when I try to crop it and show the image, I get a gray background to the right of the image. I wouldn't mind it, but when I try to apply contours to the image, the bottom and right edges are picked up as contour edges. How do I make sure that the gray padding doesn't affect my contour?

Here is my function:

```
def head_ratio(self):
    face_cascade  = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(self.gray, 1.3, 5)
    m_height, m_width, channels = self.image.shape
    x, y, w, h = faces[0]
    ROI = self.image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.float32)/10
    blurred = cv2.filter2D(self.gray[y:y+h, x:x+w], -1, kernel)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    _,contours,_ =  cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(ROI, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), 3) 
    cv2.imshow("output", ROI)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return 1
```

Thank you for your help. I have been trying to look for an answer to this but was having trouble with what to search for.